# Make C# assembly attribute show in details

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Is there a way to make assembly attributes show up when you right click-> Properties->details on an exe?
I know about the standard ones but I want to add my own (e.g. Email).

Edit: Also if there is a way to do this post build, that would be fine.

Comment: Don't use 'dotnet' for a tag - use '.net' instead. Please pay attention the suggest prompts when tagging your question - any tag with a number < 10 after the name should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The information on the Version tab is retrieved from the executable's [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx) resource (we're talking native Win32 resources here, not managed resources). By default the compiler will take information from some of the Assembly attributes and put into the VERSIONINFO resource. Unfortunately you can't change which attributes the compiler uses here, so you can't include your own information this way.

But if you really want you can create your own VERSIONINFO resource and put in a .RES file and embed in your executable using the Csc.exe /win32res compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen a pure .NET solution, but perhaps you could you combine [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/SummInfoPropSetFile.aspx) with [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100421073303/http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/custom-assemblyinfo-attributes.html)?

Comment: Your link to CodingHorror has broken.